# Problem 1: package corosync-3.1.5-1.el8.x86_64 requires corosynclib(x86-64) = 3.1.5-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed

Tags: yum

Followed the guide to install pacemaker & corosync [enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/8/availability/availability-InstallingandConfiguringPacemakerandCorosync.html#install-pacemaker) on a Oracle Linux 8 VM which essentially does the below to access the HA items:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --enable ol8_appstream ol8_baseos_latest ol8_addons
```

Which is all fine and installed perfectly.  However, now when i try to yum update i get this:

```
[root@private]# yum update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:41 ago on Mon 20 Jun 2022 10:41:09 EDT.
Error:
 Problem 1: package corosync-3.1.5-1.el8.x86_64 requires corosynclib(x86-64) = 3.1.5-1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both corosynclib-3.1.5-2.el8.x86_64 and corosynclib-3.1.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package corosynclib-3.1.5-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package corosync-3.1.5-1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 2: package pacemaker-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64 requires pacemaker-cluster-libs(x86-64) = 2.1.0-8.0.1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both pacemaker-cluster-libs-2.1.2-4.0.1.el8.x86_64 and pacemaker-cluster-libs-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package pacemaker-cluster-libs-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package pacemaker-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 3: package pacemaker-cli-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.1.0-8.0.1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both pacemaker-libs-2.1.2-4.0.1.el8.x86_64 and pacemaker-libs-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package pacemaker-libs-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package pacemaker-cli-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 4: package pcs-0.10.12-6.0.1.el8_6.1.x86_64 requires pacemaker-cli >= 2.0.0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-cli-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.1.0-8.0.1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-cli-2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.1.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-cli-2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.3.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.3, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-cli-2.0.2-3.el8_1.2.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.0.2-3.el8_1.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-cli-2.0.3-5.el8.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.0.3-5.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-cli-2.0.3-5.el8_2.1.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.0.3-5.el8_2.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-cli-2.0.4-6.el8.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.0.4-6.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-cli-2.0.4-6.el8_3.1.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.0.4-6.el8_3.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-cli-2.0.4-6.el8_3.2.x86_64 requires pacemaker-libs(x86-64) = 2.0.4-6.el8_3.2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-libs-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.x86_64 requires pacemaker-schemas = 2.1.0-8.0.1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-libs-2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.1.x86_64 requires pacemaker-schemas = 2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package pacemaker-libs-2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.3.x86_64 requires pacemaker-schemas = 2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.3, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package sbd-1.5.1-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with pacemaker-libs < 2.0.5-4 provided by pacemaker-libs-2.0.2-3.el8_1.2.x86_64
  - package sbd-1.5.1-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with pacemaker-libs < 2.0.5-4 provided by pacemaker-libs-2.0.3-5.el8.x86_64
  - package sbd-1.5.1-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with pacemaker-libs < 2.0.5-4 provided by pacemaker-libs-2.0.3-5.el8_2.1.x86_64
  - package sbd-1.5.1-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with pacemaker-libs < 2.0.5-4 provided by pacemaker-libs-2.0.4-6.el8.x86_64
  - package sbd-1.5.1-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with pacemaker-libs < 2.0.5-4 provided by pacemaker-libs-2.0.4-6.el8_3.1.x86_64
  - package sbd-1.5.1-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with pacemaker-libs < 2.0.5-4 provided by pacemaker-libs-2.0.4-6.el8_3.2.x86_64
  - cannot install both pacemaker-schemas-2.1.2-4.0.1.el8.noarch and pacemaker-schemas-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.noarch
  - cannot install both pacemaker-schemas-2.1.2-4.0.1.el8.noarch and pacemaker-schemas-2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.1.noarch
  - cannot install both pacemaker-schemas-2.1.2-4.0.1.el8.noarch and pacemaker-schemas-2.0.5-9.0.1.el8_4.3.noarch
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package sbd-1.5.1-1.el8.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package pcs-0.10.12-6.0.1.el8_6.1.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package pacemaker-schemas-2.1.0-8.0.1.el8.noarch
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this issue myself today. The message is verbose and hard to read. There is a package that can be updated (corosynclib) but its dependency (corosync) does not have a corresponding update.

Essentially, the corosync package is located in the ol8_addons repository and the corosynclib package is located in the ol8_appstream repository. Currently, there is no corresponding corosync 3.1.5-2 release required by the corosynclib 3.1.5-2 package.

I built the corosync 3.1.5-2 package from the source (SRPM) package (just as a test) and installed it.

```
rpmbuild --rebuild corosync-3.1.5-2.el8.src.rpm

dnf install corosync-3.1.5-2.el8.rpm
```

The reason for OracleLinux's missing package is not clear, perhaps it is a mistake and needs reporting to Oracle.

As with corosync, different pacemaker package versions exist in both ol8_addons and ol8_appstream repositories. Fortunately, matching package versions can be installed. To fix the situation I removed all pacemaker packages and installed afresh:

```
dnf remove pacemaker*
dnf install pacemaker-2.1.2-4.0.1.el8_6.2
```

Finally, an update should be possible and is error free:

```
dnf update
```